Do we really need a [brick] tag?
While reviewing suggested edits I came across this. Nothing wrong with the tag wiki edit (though I'm skipping in the meantime) but it's for a tag called brick, with 29 uses currently.
Is this tag really necessary? Usually we distinguish other systems from bricks, not the other way around, since the overwhelming majority of questions are about bricks, as implied by the name of the site.

This tag does not seem to add anything to the questions, many of these questions use part-identification or piece-information which describe the questions well enough. 
Only two questions used this tag alone, I have re-tagged with other more appropriate tags and removed all references to this tag on every other question.

I know I am a new user here and even made that wiki excerpt myself but when I think about brick tag, it seems useless to me. It's like having a movie tag in Movies & TV stack exchange. I will say we should get rid of that tag.

On a sidenote movies did had [tag:movies] tag and then they got rid of it.

Not only Movies, Hinduism also black Listed Hindu tag and got rid of Sanatana Dharma tag.

@NogShine having a tag which apply to almost every question make no sense

Fun fact: There even is a dedicated type of filter for blacklisting such tags (“intrinsic tag”). I suppose we here do not have this one due to the renaming from Lego to Bricks. Moderators should be able to see it here.

The word brick is not just generic for lego parts, it is also a type of part it self.
So yes, I think it should be kept incase people are asking a question regarding the type 'brick/s'.

We don't really need a tag for each type of part. Even if we did, [brick] is still too ambiguous, and it would not be immediately obvious to all users that it was referring to a type of part.

ldcad and bricklink do quite a good job of categorising parts though its not perfect of course. there is brick, brick decorated, brick modified, brick round and brick curved. However categories like technic brick, arch, slope and wedge do overlap because it is impossible to perfectly organize the lego parts library (which is over 60,000 parts)
